# Formatting jquery date without time

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am pulling the date using youtube API and injecting it into a div. I am trying to format the date properly to just display the date without the time aspect

1 Get date and format string

```
var date = new Date(data.entry.published.$t.substr(0, 4), data.entry.published.$t.substr(5, 2) - 1, data.entry.published.$t.substr(8, 2)).toLocaleDateString();
```

2 Format date string

```
var objDate = new Date(date), locale = "en-us", month = objDate.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
```

3 Display

```
$('h5').html(objDate);
```

However this executes Sat Oct 07 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time).

My question is how do I format my string to only display the month day and year

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getMonth and allied functions like below:

```
var myDate = new Date("February 3 2001");
document.write((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + myDate.getDate() + "-" + myDate.getFullYear())
```

Comment: That seems to help, anyway I can get it to display the month in words instead of #s?

Comment: Check out the answer I posted, which does exactly that

Answer (score 0):

You will need to format the date object as a string in order to get it to display the way that you want it to.

```
formatDate = function(dateObj) {
    var months = [
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        ],
        days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
        d = new Date(dateObj),
        day = days[d.getDay()],
        date = d.getDate(),
        month = months[d.getMonth()],
        year = d.getFullYear();

    return day + " " + month + " " + date + ", " + year;
};

var newDate = new Date();
alert( formatDate( newDate ) );
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QCY54/